# Addition in a fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code below:

```
    $sql="SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` NOT LIKE '%backup%' AND `Database` NOT LIKE 'mysql' AND `Database` NOT LIKE '%schema%'";
 $query=mysql_query($sql,$connect); 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $sql1="SHOW TABLES FROM `".$row['Database']."`"; 
         $query1=mysql_query($sql1, $connect);
         while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1) ) {
         $row2=implode(" ",$row2);
          $sql1="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$row['Database']."`.`".$row2."`";
          $query1=mysql_query($sql1,$connect);  
          echo implode(" ",mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)).'<br>';
         }
 }
```

I have two database,and two tables,with two records
The above code count each record of each table from each database,and it will fetch two arrays contaning the records number of each table.

So it will output:

```
2
2
```

What i need is to sum them,so the result will be 4.Help please?

Comment: i know,but at the moment i have to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count the sum in PHP:

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` NOT LIKE '%backup%' AND `Database` NOT LIKE 'mysql' AND `Database` NOT LIKE '%schema%'";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect); 
$total = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sql1="SHOW TABLES FROM `".$row['Database']."`"; 
    $query1=mysql_query($sql1, $connect);

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1) ) {
        $row2=reset($row2);
        $sql2="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$row['Database']."`.`".$row2."`";
        $query2=mysql_query($sql2,$connect);  
        $total += mysql_result($query2, 0);
    }
}

echo $total;
```

And also stop using **mysql_*** functions, they are deprecated...

Comment: "Only variables should be passed by reference" "reset() expects parameter 1 to be array,"- is not working

Comment: it's working,thanks,i would voteup but i dont have enough rep

Comment: ,i found an issue...try adding more records.The result its 4 , even if i am adding more records

Comment: there is problem, that you are overwritting `query1`... see my edit